# Does sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression always converge to best solution?

Tags: scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization, logistic-regression

When using this code, I've noticed that it converges unbelievably quickly (small
fraction of one second), even when the model and/or the data is very large.  I
suspect that in some cases I am not getting anything close to the best solution,
but this is hard to prove. It would be nice to have the option for some type of
global optimizer such as the basin hopping algorithm, even if this consumed 100
to 1,000 times as much CPU.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this subject?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a very complex question and this answer might be incomplete, but should give you some hints (as your question also indicates some knowledge gaps):

- (1) First i disagree with the desire for `some type of global optimizer such as the basin hopping algorithm, even if this consumed 100 to 1,000 times as much CPU` as this does not help in most cases (in ML world) as the differences are so subtle and the **optimization-error will often be negligible compared to the other errors (model-power; empirical-risk)**

  - Read `"Stochastic Gradient Descent Tricks" (Battou)` for some overview (and the error-components!)
  - He even gives a very important reason to use fast approximate algorithms (not necessarily a good fit in your case if 1000x training-time is not a problem): *approximate optimization can achieve better expected risk because more training examples can be processed during the allowed time*
- (2) **Basin-hopping** is some of these highly *heuristic tools* of global-optimization (looking for global-minima instead of local minima) without any guarantees at all (touching NP-hardness and co.). **It's the last algorithm you want to use here (see point (3))!**
- (3) **The problem of logistic-regression is a convex optimization problem!**

  - **The local minimum is always the global-minimum**, which follows from convexity (i'm ignoring stuff like strictly/unique solutions and co)!
  - Therefore you will always use something tuned for convex-optimization! And never Basin-hopping!
- (4) There are different solvers and each support different variants of problems (different regularization and co.). We don't know exactly what you are optimizing, but of course these solvers are working differently in regards to convergence:

  - **Take the following comments with a grain of salt**:
  - **liblinear**: is probably using some CG-based algorithm (conjugated-gradient) which means convergence is highly dependent on the data

    - if accurate convergence is achieved is solely depending on the exact implementation (liblinear is high-quality)
    - as it's a first-order method i would call the general accuracy *medium*
  - **sag/saga**: seems to have a better convergence-theory (did not check it much), but again: it's dependent on your data as mentioned in [sklearn's docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) and if solutions are accurate is highly depending on the implementation details

    - as these are first-order methods: general accuracy *medium*
  - **newton-cg**: an inexact newton-method

    - in general much more robust in terms of convergence as line-searches replace heuristics or constant learning-rates (LS costly in first-order opt)
    - second-order method with inexact-core: expected accuracy: *medium-high*
  - **lbfgs**: quasi-newton method

    - again in general much more robust in terms of convergence like newton-cg
    - second-order method: expected accuracy: *medium-high*

Of course second-order methods get more hurt with large-scale data (even complexity-wise) and as mentioned, not all solvers are supporting every logreg-optimization-problem supported in sklearn.

**I hope you get the idea how complex this question is (because of highly complex solver-internals).**

**Most important things**:

- LogReg is convex -> use solvers tuned for unconstrained convex optimization
- If you want medium-high accuracy: use those second-order based methods available and do many iterations (it's a parameter)
- If you want high accuracy: use second-order based methods which are even more conservative/careful (no: hessian-approx; inverse-hessian-approx; truncating...):

  - e.g. any off-the-shelve solver from convex-optimization
  - Open-source: [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/), [ecos](https://github.com/embotech/ecos) and co.
  - Commercial: Mosek
  - (but you need to formulate the model yourself in their frameworks or some wrapper; probably some examples for classic logistic-regression available)
- As expected: some methods will get very slow with much data.

Comment: I'd forgotten that logistic regression is a specific form of maximum likelihood estimation.

But, I don't believe that likelihood functions are in general convex.  See, e.g., the discussion here: https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/econ620/reviewm5.pdf